# how does temperature influence spray paint usage?

Tags: painting, spraying

I've got 3 pieces of plywood, all 120x30x1 cm, that I want to spray paint matte black.

Ideally, I will be doing this outside next weekend. The weather should be a high of around 10C, partly cloudy, bit of a breeze.

Will working at around 5C ambient influence my spray painting? Will the dispersal be affected?  the drying time? anything else I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

10 C or 50 F is not the optimal temp for aerosol spray painting, but should be OK. Most manufacturers recommend 60 F or above, but I wouldn't worry too much. The product will spray fine, the dry time may be a bit longer but it will dry fine. Try to get the painted pieces indoors to a warmer area as soon as they can be handled, and your paint will cure properly.  Good Luck.